# MS Access query increment by one when comparing

Tags: ms-access

```
SELECT Student_Number,
DATEPART("yyyy", Starting_Date) AS Starting_Year,
DATEPART("yyyy",Ending_Date) AS Ending_Year
FROM   PGME
WHERE  ID = 1
```

Display as below

```
Student_Number    Starting_Year Ending_Year
003329497         1994          1999
```

Is there any way I can compare with "Starting_Date" and "Ending_Date", if "Starting_Date" < "Ending_Year", the "Starting_Year" will be increased by one which is

```
Student_Number    Starting_Year Ending_Year
003329497         1994          1999
003329497         1995          1999
003329497         1996          1999
003329497         1997          1999
003329497         1998          1999
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHERE
    DatePart('yyyy', Starting_Date) BETWEEN 1994 AND 1998 AND
    DatePart('yyyy', Ending_Date) = 1999
```

... will automatically include all the starting years from 1994 up to 1998. There is no need to increment anything.

If the query yields duplicate years, then either use a DISTINCT or a GROUP BY clause. The query will however not complement missing years.

---

If you want to modify existing records, make an UPDATE query:

```
UPDATE PGME
SET Starting_Date = DateAdd('yyyy', 1, Starting_Date)
WHERE DatePart('yyyy', Starting_Date) < DatePart('yyyy', Ending_Date)
```

(I'm not sure what you are asking)